# Removing relationship logic from view in laravel

Tags: templates, laravel, laravel-4, relationship, laravel-blade

I currently have a situation where one of my models uses a 'belongsTo' relationship with the user model.

Within 'article' model:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

Right now I'm doing this in the view, which seems to work, but I feel like I'm doing logic where I shouldn't be. If I need to use this again in another view then I'd need to recreate the logic.

```
@if($article->author)
    {{ $article->author->username }} 
@else
    [deleted]
@endif
```

So what's the best way to approach this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is completely fine. I don't see any wrong with that. However, You might experiencing `N + 1` problem. If you are not eager loading author relationship, Laravel will run a query each time when you try to access author relationship in view. For example, `$article->author->username` will run a query each time you want to retrieve username.

```
@if($article->author)
    {{ $article->author->username }} 
@else
```

To avoid `N + 1` problem, you can eager load the relationship.

For example:

```
$article = Article::with('author')->find(1);
```

More info:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's good to know I'm at least doing something right, hard to tell sometimes. Thanks for the tip about eager loading, I'll be sure to make sure of that from now on.